# Uncaught Error: Module name "apple-icloud" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im trying to get a node app working in my JS app (firebase).
The implementation of the code is like below...

But I am getting the error that I posted in the title..

Uncaught Error: Module name "apple-icloud" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

how would i change this implementation for this to work?

```
const iCloud = require('apple-icloud');


var session = {}; // An empty session. Has to be a session object or file path that points on a JSON file containing your session
var username = "EMAIL"; // Your apple id
var password = "PW"; // Your password

// This creates your iCloud instance
var myCloud = new iCloud(session, username, password);

myCloud.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("Ready Event!");
  // Check if the two-factor-authentication is required
  if (myCloud.twoFactorAuthenticationIsRequired) {
    // Get the security code using node-prompt
    prompt.get(["Security Code"], async function(err, input) {
      if (err) return console.error(err);
      const code = input["Security Code"];
      // Set the security code to the instance
      myCloud.securityCode = code;
    });
  }
  else {
    // Now the 'ready' event fired but 'twoFactorAuthenticationIsRequired' is false, which means we don't need it (anymore)
    console.log("You are logged in completely!");
  }
});
```